# Detect occurence of 504 while processing django view

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, http-status-code-504

I have a view which sometimes, takes a long time to process resulting in a timeout.

I could handle this heavy processing in the background using background tasks in as celery. This for me however is not optimal because, I need to give
feedback to the user, like imediately.

Whenever I get timeouts, bad things happen and I end up with a model objects in an inconsistent state, missing some vital variables. I could easily remedy this by using atomic transactions but I dont know how to
see a 504 event from the view. If it helps, I running django behind nginx

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some relevant code?

Comment: You may increase the timeout. But if you can switch to background processing, better take this way. You can still give immediate feedbacks.